# SMTPSendFailedException when trying to send an email in JSP

Tags: java, email, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to make a new registered user in the web app receive an email for confirmation purposes, but after a long search and debugging other problems, I'm stuck on this one and haven't found a solution.
This is the code of the java server page and the error with the stack trace I get.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 

    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%> 

<!DOCTYPE html> 

<%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*"%> 

<%@ page import = "javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%> 

<%@ page import = "javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %> 

<% 

// code of sending email 

String result; 

// Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned. 

String to = "email recipient"; 

// Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned 

String from = "myemail” 

// Assuming you are sending email from localhost 

String host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 

// Get system properties object 

Properties properties = System.getProperties(); 

// Setup mail server  

properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);  

// Get the default Session object. 

Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties); 

try { 

      // Create a default MimeMessage object. 

      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession); 

       

      // Set From: header field of the header. 

      message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from)); 

       

      // Set To: header field of the header. 

      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, 

                               new InternetAddress(to)); 

      // Set Subject: header field  

      message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!"); 

       

      // Now set the actual message 

      message.setText("This is actual message"); 

       

      // Send message 

      Transport.send(message); 

      result = "Sent message successfully...."; 

   }  catch (MessagingException e) { 

       throw new RuntimeException(e); 

   } 

// ends here code to send email 

%> 

<html> 

   <head> 

      <title>Send Email using JSP</title> 

   </head> 

    

   <body> 

      <center> 

         <h1>Send Email using JSP</h1> 

      </center> 

       

      <p align = "center"> 

         <%  

            out.println("Result: " + result + "\n"); 

         %> 

      </p> 

   </body> 

</html>
```

The error I'm getting:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/email.jsp] at line [42] 

 

39:       Transport.send(message); 

40:       result = "Sent message successfully...."; 

41:    }  catch (MessagingException e) { 

42:        throw new RuntimeException(e); 

43:    } 

44: // ends here code to send email 

45: %> 

 

 

Stacktrace: 

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:611) 

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:500) 

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:378) 

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:326) 

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) 

org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) 

Root Cause 

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. z8sm11494198wrh.37 - gsmtp 

 

org.apache.jsp.email_jsp._jspService(email_jsp.java:168) 

org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71) 

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) 

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:467) 

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:378) 

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:326) 

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) 

org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) 

Root Cause 

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. z8sm11494198wrh.37 - gsmtp 

 

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057) 

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1580) 

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1097) 

javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195) 

javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124) 

org.apache.jsp.email_jsp._jspService(email_jsp.java:165) 

org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71) 

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) 

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:467) 

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:378) 

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:326) 

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) 

org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

My web deplyment assembly:

[image]

Comment: I'm not close to a computer to give you a better example but in order to send email thru gmail you will need to use smtps (secure) port and tell your client too use a secure socket factory. There are examples you can look up online. The TLS message is likely a byproduct of your mail API not doing that and gmail insisting you should. You will also have to do it as a specific user whose security in gmail has been set to allow it's use for smtp authentication.

Comment: How can I change that?

Comment: You can post an answer instead of answering in edit comment,

Comment: @JoãoMoreira Please don't add `[Fixed]` to your question. The fact that it's fixed doesn't help anyone else arriving here. If you solved your problem in a way that can benefit others with the same problem, it is better to post a detailed answer

Comment: @Tomerikoo I have replied with the answer that worked for me, I hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

**Notice:** Answer is very long, sorry, but I'll try to be as brief as possible, while showing everything that made my code eventually work, for those of you stuck on this.
I'm a college student, so I'm not the most qualified to answer this, but this is my attempt to be as clear and concise possible.

The code you see above didn't work for me and it threw me for a loop. It just has some caveats that may stop you from actually send the email and get you errors, like I did.
The code you'll see below worked for me and it's working for the purpose I want it to; to send an email to a user upon registering.

The problems I encountered when trying to implement this are 2 main ones:

- Your gmail account that you set up to send the emails isn't allowing you to send the email due to security reasons.
- Your antivirus may be messing it up.

How to solve these:

- To solve the first, it's rather simple and it only requires you to go to the email account you set up in gmail to use as your sender and change 2 settings that may impact how gmail interacts with the code you write.
  On the gmail account you set up, go to the cog icon and select "See all settings", then choose the Forwarding and POP/IMAP tab. Enable both POP download for all mail and Enable IMAP access, save the settings and try the code.
- If that change doesn't cut it, then try going to the icon of your account and clicking "Manage your Google Account", go to the Security Settings and look for "Less secure app access", turn it on, save changes and try again. Don't undo the previous step!

Other than these 2 changes, check your antivirus and/or try to disable it for a bit, then try it again. I found that my colleague was running McAfee Antivirus on his computer and I only use Windows Defender. For me it worked, for him, he had to turn off his antivirus. Maybe someone who knows more than I do can answer why this happens.
Below, I'll put my code that sends the email. Make sure to switch 2 things in the code:

- The email under `String to = email;` make sure you switch that and put the email you want to send emails from. For me it's the variable email that the user writes on a text box, you can try putting in your personal email there and checking it.
- The password under `String pass ="your password";` to the password of the email you create for the sending purpose.

Take a look at the imports, because you will need a few .jar files. For the database, you'll need the database connector jar file and for the mail imports you'll need the activation-jaf jar file and the java-mail jar file, all can be found on the internet. Add them to your Classpath in your project's Build Path. After these, you'll need to go to the properties again and select Deployment Assembly -> Add these same jars to it, after that, you should be set up and can try this code, albeit with some changes.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*"%> 
<%@ page import = "javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%>
<%@ page import = "javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>

<%
String user = request.getParameter("username");
String pwd = request.getParameter("password");
String fullname = request.getParameter("name");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
int a=0;

//database connection to Apache Tomcat
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename", "root", "password");
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rset;
        rset = stat.executeQuery("select * from user where username ='" + user + "' or email='" + email +"'");

        if(rset.next()) {
            %>
<script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("Username or email already in use!");
                    window.location="register.jsp";
            </script>
<%
} else {
int i = stat.executeUpdate("insert into user (username, password, name, email, active) values('" + user + "','"
        + pass + "','" + nome + "','" + email + "',0)");

if (i > 0) {
    String result;

    // code for sending email
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    //The email you're sending from
    String from = "email@gmail.com";
    //The password
    String password ="password";
    // Where it's going to, in this case, it takes a user input for its email
    String to = email;



    // Get system properties
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    // Setup mail server
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    // Get the default Session object.
    Session sess = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    try{
     // Create a default MimeMessage object.
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(sess);

     // Set From: header field of the header.
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

     // Set To: header field of the header.
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                              new InternetAddress(to));

     // Set Subject: header field
     message.setSubject("Successful Registration Email | VidTek");

     // Now set the actual message
     message.setContent("Message for the Content you want in the email.");

     // Send message
     Transport transport = sess.getTransport("smtp");
     transport.connect(host, from, password);
     transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
     transport.close();
     result = "Sent message successfully....";
     } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
        result = "Error: unable to send message...." + mex;
     }
    // ends here code to send email
    response.sendRedirect("active.jsp"); 
    } 
    else {
    response.sendRedirect("register.jsp");
}
}
%>
```

If you change some of these names to the ones you have, after the changes made, it should send an email with whatever subject and content you want.